# Call lambda function from a different cloudformation stack via API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function exposed via API gateway but when I try to request it using fetch it is saying that I am forbidden to access it. How do I allow my function to call another function via API gateway?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for it.

1. Check whether your API gateway endpoint is open or not. While specifying trigger for lambda you must have selected one option for security. You can edit this in API gateway Method Execution tab under Authorization Settings, select Authorization : None and API key required: false
2. You might not have enabled CORS on your api and due to that your api is not available on cross regions.
3. Your api gateway is not having access to lambda function. You can do that by attaching IAM role to your API gateway API which can trigger your lambda function.

Comment: Do I still need to do the 1 and 2 if I already attached IAM role that can trigger the lambda function via API gateway?

Comment: Yes you need to do 1 and 2